# RxSwift Multiple subscriptions to same Observable in for-loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, subscription, rx-swift

I need to execute a task multiple times inside a for-loop. The task itself returns `Observable<Void>`. I feel that I may run into some unexpected errors by continuously subscribing. **Is it okay to subscribe n times in `for-loop`?**

```
private func removeItem(from locations: Resource...) {
    for resource in locations {
        RemoveItemTask(id: item.value.id, resource: resource)
            .execute(in: self.dispatcher)
            .subscribe { event in
                if let error = event.error {
                    self.error = Observable.of(error)
                }
            }.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Observable' is a monad, i.e. a functional programming control flow 
solution, i.e. a _replacement_ for loops, if/else, and such. Mixing functional and imperative styles of programming can hardly be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use a for-loop? `RxSwift` has a lot of interesting solutions you can use.

So you have some tasks, you can `map` them into an array of observables without calling `subscribe`:

```
let observables: [Observable<Void>] = locations.map({ ... })
```

And then handle all the errors:

```
Observable
    .merge(observables.map({ $0.materialize() }))
    .flatMap({ Observable.from(optional: $0.error) })
    .subscribe(onNext: { (error) in
        // Handle error
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```